# $_REQUEST works, but $_POST doesn't -

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Thank you for sharing in my headache - here is the short speil:

Recently inherited a poorly coded WordPress site - which leveraged a WP Contact Form 7 -

I stripped all the WP-CF code out (due to the fact that the WordPress had been stripped out before it was handed over to me) -- just to make a simple patch script and get on with real work.

I replaced the WPCF scripts with this one: (to make things as easy as possible for me):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 $ = jQuery;
 console.log("Ready");
 $("#quack-button").click(function(e) {
   console.log("Quack"); 
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   POSTDATA = $.param($("#quack-form").serializeArray());
   $.ajax({
     method : "POST",
     url : "http://www.domain.com/contact.php",
     data : POSTDATA,
     success : function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      alert("Thank you ! We'll get in touch as soon as we can -! ");
     }
   });
 });
});
```

but, after trying many different forms/combinations of `$.param` and `serialize` - 
The server side script continued to return a blank array....

`print_r($_POST);`

However, when I changed it to `print_r($_REQUEST)` - it all worked, fine....

Now, what possible ways could this even happen? What blindspots am I missing that could create this sort of scenario...?

This is the most baffling I've dealt with in some time... I appreciate any understanding anyone can throw at this...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to send it as `$_POST`, change this line:

```
method: 'POST'
```

to this:

```
type: 'POST'
```

According to [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), thats the way of setting it.

> type (default: `'GET'`) 
>   Type: String 
>   The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". **Note:** Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

Comment: Really? When did they change that??

Comment: @rm - unless it is expecting type to be set and is defaulting to get otherwise. Then it makes perfect sense

Comment: Right, right, right - I would've sworn I've been using `method` for a long time, now....

Comment: Well, I hope that is the dumbest mistake I ever make.

Comment: @rm-vanda i do not know whether `method` was used before, haven't seen a changelog from `method` to `type` anyway, been using this eversince

Comment: method is for HTML forms, type is for jQuery's AJAX wrappers

Comment: Welp, I am as relieved as I feel stupid. 
Thanks, @Ghost - you still have 7 or so minutes before I can accept this as the answer.

Comment: To be clear, since you're defining method not type, type defaults to GET as mentioned in Ghost's answer above, so you'd be able to access your variables in PHP with $_GET or $_REQUEST

Comment: Right, which is why I feel especially stupid. That was the first thing I should've figured ~